# And another NPE

Tags: java, android, fragment

I got 3 fragments, 2 are player1 and player2, and one is tictactoelayout and one that basically concatonates all them fragments together which is the TicTacToeGame. In each of my player fragments I'm trying to gain access to a TicTacToeGame method

```
public class PlayerTurn1 extends Fragment  {

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
    ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.playerturn1, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

       extras = getArguments();

       player1 = new ArrayList<String>(extras.getStringArrayList("player1"));

        row = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.rowP1);
        column = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.columnP1);
        p1Name = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.p1NameInfo);
        p1Icon = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.p1IconInfo);
        doneP1 = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.doneP1);
        resetP1 = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.resetP2);

        setPlayer();

        doneP1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {          
            public void onClick(View v) {   

                if(checkField() != false)
                {
                    String rowValueStr = row.getText().toString();
                    String colValueStr = column.getText().toString();
                    int rowValueInt = Integer.parseInt(rowValueStr);
                    int colValueInt = Integer.parseInt(colValueStr);

                    myObject.playTicTacToe(rowValueInt, colValueInt);
                    myObject.whosTurn = 2;
                    callPlayer2Fragment();

                }


            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here's my Player2 fragment:

```
public class PlayerTurn2 extends Fragment{
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
    ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.playerturn2, container, false);

        return view;
    }

    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);


        extras = getArguments();

        player2 = new ArrayList<String>(extras.getStringArrayList("player2"));

        p2Name = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.p2NameInfo);
        p2Icon = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.p2IconInfo);
        row = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.rowP2);
        column = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.columnP2);
        doneP2 = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.doneP2);
        resetP2 = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.resetP2);

        setPlayer();

        doneP2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {          
            public void onClick(View v) {   

                if(checkField() != false)
                {
                    String rowValueStr = row.getText().toString();
                    String colValueStr = column.getText().toString();
                    int rowValueInt = Integer.parseInt(rowValueStr);
                    int colValueInt = Integer.parseInt(colValueStr);

                    myObject2.playTicTacToe(rowValueInt, colValueInt);
                    myObject2.whosTurn = 1;
                    callPlayer1Fragment();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here's my method located in TicTacToeGame:

```
public void playTicTacToe(int r, int c)
    {
        if(whosTurn == 1)
            images[r-1][c-1].setText(player1.get(1));  
        else
            images[r-1][c-1].setText(player2.get(1));
        return;

    }
```

Here's the log cat:

```
03-26 15:11:31.770: E/AndroidRuntime(5632): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-26 15:11:31.770: E/AndroidRuntime(5632):     at As2.packageTK.TicTacToeGame.playTicTacToe(TicTacToeGame.java:153)
03-26 15:11:31.770: E/AndroidRuntime(5632):     at As2.packageTK.PlayerTurn1$1.onClick(PlayerTurn1.java:64)
```

line 64:

```
myObject.playTicTacToe(rowValueInt, colValueInt);
```

line 153:

```
images[r-1][c-1].setText("O");
```

Any ideas how to resolve this?

**EDIT**

```
    TextView[][] images;
image1 = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.Image1);
        image2 = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.Image2);
        image3 = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.Image3);
        image4 = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.Image4);
        image5 = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.Image5);
        image6 = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.Image6);
        image7 = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.Image7);
        image8 = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.Image8);
        image9 = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.Image9);

    images = new TextView[][]{ {image1, image2, image3},
                       {image4, image5, image6},
                       {image7, image8, image9} }
```

;

Comment: what is line 153 in `TicTacToeGame.java`?

Comment: Did you set a breakpoint there to see which variable is `null`?

Comment: Make `myObject` non-null? I don't see anywhere where you initialize `myObject` or `myObject2`. Also, use your debugger. The debugger is your friend. Love it, cherish it, debug like no one is watching.

Comment: I did instantiate them ill post it and i posted line 153

Comment: It appears you haven't initialized `images[r-1][c-1]`... As @kcoppock said, "The debugger is your friend."

Comment: @Sam I did... I just don't want to post all the uncessiable declarations. I tried to see if images[][] contains anything and it does. I'll redit the thing just for you

Comment: Is the **real** code `setText("O")` or `setText(player1.get(1))`?  ... This makes a **Huge** difference and I just wasted a half hour with another developer that deliberately posted the wrong code... Honestly I'm not in the mood to play this game again.

Comment: Also, you're calling `setText()` on an array called images? If those are textviews, that's a bit of a misnomer.

Comment: They're textviews and the setText(player1.get(1)) is an arraylist of string. It has two field 0 = name of the player and 1 = the icon picked and yes it setText(player1.get(1))

Comment: @Sam I'm not lieing about my code dude. I'm just posting the essential. The problem lies in the object calling the TicTacToeGame. If you don't want to answer fine by me.

Comment: I toned down the language, obviously I'm jaded for the next hour or so... but clearly you are too. We should both check our attitudes. :) Anyway NullPointerExceptions are one of the easiest errors to track down and the debugger is one of the best tools a developer has, you should spend the time to get to know it well.

Comment: Chill, found it, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

> Any ideas how to resolve this?

Yes.  Analyse the code carefully.

You say that the NPE is thrown in this statement.

```
images[r-1][c-1].setText("O");
```

- Both `r` and `c` are `int`, therefore **cannot** be `null`.
- The `images` array **could** be `null`.
- The `images[r-1]` subarray **could** be `null`.
- The `images[r-1][c-1]` object **could** be `null`.

(If that is not where the exception is thrown, then do similar analysis on the actual code where the NPE is thrown.)

So you have exactly 3 possible immediate causes of an NPE.  Use the debugger or trace prints to work out which of the above is actually `null`.  Then look at the code that creates, initializes and updates the array to figure out where those `null` values are coming from.  Then fix the problem.

I can't help you find the source of the nulls because the relevant code has not been included in the Question.

Answer (score 1):

From the LogCat:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at As2.packageTK.TicTacToeGame.playTicTacToe(TicTacToeGame.java:153)
```

You can see the problem is in `playTicTacToe()` (specifically on line 153, but there no way I can determine which line this is). If this is the complete method:

```
public void playTicTacToe(int r, int c)
{
    if(whosTurn == 1)
        images[r-1][c-1].setText(player1.get(1));  
    else
        images[r-1][c-1].setText(player2.get(1));
    return;
}
```

Then `images[r-1][c-1]`, `player1`, and/or `player2` is null...  Your debugger will help you figure out which values are null much faster than we can, then simply initialize the variable(s).
NPE aren't all that bad.